# How to reverse multiple lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
scores=open('scores.csv','r')


for score in scores.readlines():
    score = score.strip()
    rev=[]
    for s in reversed(score[0:]):
        rev.append(s)
    print(rev)
```

This is my code, what I am going to do is the print reversed list from scores.csv

If I print `scores` at the beginning, the result is:

`['0.74,0.63,0.58,0.89\n', '0.91,0.89,0.78,0.99\n', '0.43,0.35,0.34,0.45\n', '0.56,0.61,0.66,0.58\n', '0.50,0.49,0.76,0.72\n', '0.88,0.75,0.61,0.78\n']`

It looks normal, and if I print `score` after I remove all `\n` in the list, the result is:

```
0.74,0.63,0.58,0.89
0.91,0.89,0.78,0.99
0.43,0.35,0.34,0.45
0.56,0.61,0.66,0.58
0.50,0.49,0.76,0.72
0.88,0.75,0.61,0.78
```

it still looks ok, but if I print at the end of the code, it shows:

```
['9', '8', '.', '0', ',', '8', '5', '.', '0', ',', '3', '6', '.', '0', ',', '4', '7', '.', '0']
['9', '9', '.', '0', ',', '8', '7', '.', '0', ',', '9', '8', '.', '0', ',', '1', '9', '.', '0']
['5', '4', '.', '0', ',', '4', '3', '.', '0', ',', '5', '3', '.', '0', ',', '3', '4', '.', '0']
['8', '5', '.', '0', ',', '6', '6', '.', '0', ',', '1', '6', '.', '0', ',', '6', '5', '.', '0']
['2', '7', '.', '0', ',', '6', '7', '.', '0', ',', '9', '4', '.', '0', ',', '0', '5', '.', '0']
['8', '7', '.', '0', ',', '1', '6', '.', '0', ',', '5', '7', '.', '0', ',', '8', '8', '.', '0']
```

looks like python converts my result from decimal to integer, but when I am trying to use `float(s)` to convert it back, it gives me an error. I would like to know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: you should use the `csv` module for starters

Comment: "looks like python converts my result from decimal to integer" absolutely **not**. There are no operations in your code that can yield an integer or float. You wouldn't see the quotes if those were numbers. What is happening is that you are building a list of characters. which is not the same thing as a string, hence why you see the extra `[]` and commas. Try: `''.join(rev)` to convert the list back into a string.

Comment: Anyway, I believe you'd like the output to start with `0.89,0.58,0.63,0.74`. but your code is reversing character-by-character not field-by-field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your approach, `score` is a string, so it's doing exactly what you tell it to: reverse the entire line character by character. You can do two things:

1. Use the `csv` module to read your CSV file (recommended), to get a list of float values, then reverse that.
2. Split your line on commas, then reverse that list, and finally stitch it back together. An easy way to reverse a list in Python is `mylist[::-1]`.

For number 2, it would be something like:

```py
score = score.strip()
temp = score.split(',')
temp_reversed = temp[::-1]
score_reversed = ','.join(temp_reversed)
```

Answer (score 0):

*always* use `csv` module to read csv files. This module parses the data, splits according to commas, etc...

Your attempt is just reversing the line char by char. I'd rewrite it completely using `csv` module, which yields the tokens already split by comma (default):

```
import csv
with open('scores.csv','r') as scores:

    cr = csv.reader(scores)
    rev = []
    for row in cr:
       rev.append(list(reversed(row))
```

that doesn't convert data to float, that said, I'd replace the loop by a comprehension + float conversion

```
rev = [[float(x) for x in reversed(row)] for row in cr]
```